# How to parse body of Content-type: application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json

Tags: java, playframework-2.5, contentful

I am trying to parse a request body where

`Content-type: application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json`

When I give `Content-type: application/json`

it works fine but Contentful CMS passes the above content-type so I have to parse this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using the contentful Java SDK right ?

That header is filled by the SDK, is there a reason that you need to parse that header ?

Comment: I am trying to integrate my webhook in Contentful. The contentful triggers the api with header Content-type : application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json and my java play application is unable to parse the body. As it expects application/json as Content-type

Comment: @Indrajeet can't you just expect that header instead of application/header in your code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

> If the body is of type json it by default look for Content-type application/json in header.

To avoid the validation of the Content-Type header is JSON I used this and it worked.

> @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.TolerantJson.class)